# How can I get a specific string between two string in python

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping

I am trying to get a specific string in a specific position. The string I have is a Json inside html page I tried to locate it using HTML tags But I could not [The site I want to scarap](https://www.sephora.com/product/laura-mercier-mini-tinted-moisturizer-broad-spectrum-spf-20-oil-free-P466665?icid2=just%20dropped:p466665:product)
the string I want to get is: `"isOnlyFewLeft":false,"isOutOfStock":false,"isRopisEligibleSku":true,"isSephoraExclusive":false,"`

I tried the following pattern: `'''"isOutOfStock": (.*?), "isRopisEligibleSku"'''` But it did not work.
My code: ```

````
def Filter(self):
    try:
        print(self.sourcepage)
        match = re.search('''"isOutOfStock": (.*?), "isRopisEligibleSku"''', self.sourcepage)
        print(match)
        if match:
            print(match.group())
    except BaseException as e:
        print(e)```
````

Comment: Remove spaces, or use `'"isOutOfStock":\s*(.*?),\s*"isRopisEligibleSku"'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew , Eng.Hassan Ibraheem despite of the fact that suggestion is working note that it's a very bad practice to use regex in web-scraping

Comment: @JaSON What do you suggest?

Comment: I suggest to get content of required script node by its `id` attribute (`"linkStore"`) and parse it like JSON

Comment: @JaSON I tried your idea which is extremely better than using Regex. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try to get required values by parsing `script` HTML-element as JSON:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

url = 'https://www.sephora.com/product/laura-mercier-mini-tinted-moisturizer-broad-spectrum-spf-20-oil-free-P466665?icid2=just%20dropped:p466665:product'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
script = soup.select('#linkStore')[0].text
content = json.loads(script)

product_info = content['page']['product']['ancillarySkus'][0]
print(product_info['isOnlyFewLeft'],
      product_info['isOutOfStock'],
      product_info['isSephoraExclusive'],
      product_info['isRopisEligibleSku'])
```

Output:

```
(False, False, False, True)
```